# Does $f(x) = \frac {1}{(\tan x)^2}$ has any x-intercepts?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, singularity

I want to draw the following function
$$f(x) = \frac {1}{(\tan x)^2}$$

My intuition tells me that it does not have any x-intercepts because the numerator will never equal to zero but the online grapher shows me otherwise.

Should I put open dots or closed dots around the x-intercepts?

Comment: Use limit, if $\tan x\to\infty$ at $x=\frac\pi2+\pi\times n$, then $f(x)\to0$ at these points. Without that these are indeterminate. Also $\LaTeX$ support `\tan` for $\tan$.

Answer (score 1):

The function is never actually equal to $0$, but it does however tend to $0$ whenever $x$ tends to some multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$.
This is because $tan(x)$ is not defined for $x=\frac{n\pi}{2}$ (where $n$ is a whole number).
So the function doesn't actually intercept the x-axis, it just gets infinitely close to it.
This means If you have to draw the function, put open dots on the x-intercepts.